# Is RestEasy the right choice?

Tags: resteasy

Of the JAX-RS implementations it seems RestEasy is the most difficult to get help for. If you look at the mailing list archive for the project at SourceForge you will notice almost none of the questions are answered or at least I have not seen one that was answered. On the JBoss community site there is very little discussion regarding the project.

Is it an unwanted child? I am starting to think it was a mistake choosing it as the JAX-RS implementation for our projects.

Answer (score 4):

It is a good implementation BUT since this is JBOSS (RED) they want money for support and hence no support. Since it supports the JAX-RS spec it should be easy to switch. Just a little effort :-)

Answer (score 0):

Resteasy has problems in the way Providers are looked up. In my case, my REST-Client had to be WAR1 (deployed on server1) talking to RESTful implementation in WAR2 deployed on server 2.

The big problem I had was that ResteasyProviderFactory tries to scan all the jars for Providers and registered them. The IO operations (getResource() on Classloader) locks couple of JAR files in the server process because of which the undeployment of WAR1 (client) was failing

Hope this helps