# RESTEasy or Jersey?

Tags: web-services, rest, jersey, resteasy

I have a requirement for RESTFul webservices. It is up to my team to decide whether to go with Jersey or Restlet or RESTEasy or anything else. after omitting other frameworks, we are not able to choose between RESTEasy and Jersey.

Since both of them seem to be almost the same, what should we consider?

The client API should be simple and rich. We are already using JBoss 5.1 in production.

Please let me know the pros and cons of Jersey and RESTEasy. Except that it is from JBoss, I'm not able to find any valid point over Jersey.

Comment: Similar Questions. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80799/jax-rs-frameworks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80799/jax-rs-frameworks) [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459795/how-to-choose-between-jersey-apache-wink-and-jboss-resteasy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459795/how-to-choose-between-jersey-apache-wink-and-jboss-resteasy) [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572691/is-resteasy-the-right-choice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572691/is-resteasy-the-right-choice)

Comment: I don't recommend Jersey (I only tried v 2.5.1) one bit. It's extremely hard to configure and setup in the first place.

Answer (score 27):

One nice value-add feature of Jersey is the Jersey Test Framework which lets you run and test your Jersey REST services inside JUnit, without the need to first deploy them to a stand-alone server and even before you commit your code to your repo.

These tests are easy to write, you can run them before you even check in your Jersey web service code to make sure your service is working, and they become part of your automated test suite which helps enforce the contract your services have with your clients.

See [this](http://usna86-techbits.blogspot.com/2013/03/increase-quality-and-productivity-with.html) article for more information if you're using Jersety 1.X or [this one](http://usna86-techbits.blogspot.co.il/2013/12/jersey-jerseytest-migration-from-1x-to.html) for 2.x.

Another nice feature is support for the REST MVC pattern, which would allow you to return a View from your Jersey services rather than just data (the Model).  Compatibility with the Jersey Test Framework is still maturing in this regard, but it is workable.

See this article for more information on that:

http://usna86-techbits.blogspot.com/2013/12/jersey-jerseytest-migration-from-1x-to.html

Comment: Doesn't RESTEasy have the same thing? https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.1.GA/userguide/html/RESTEasy_Server-side_Mock_Framework.html

Answer (score 6):

I think the REST API & the implementation is almost like a very vanilla features. So both works the same way. But one major difference is in RESTEasy it is very difficult to generate the WADL API.Especially when the customers want to check the REST APi calls., the WADL will help a lot like WSDL.

Comment: there is not such a thing as "REST APi calls" WSDL WADL is specifically for RPC not REST.

Comment: There is a WADL for REST. It is easy to generate for Jersey implementations (http://blah/application.wadl) but harder for RESTEasy. You can add a maven plugin to do it, see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301744/can-i-get-application-wadl-file-using-resteasy

Comment: WADL: Web Application Description Language file (the WADL),https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19776-01/820-4867/ghmfe/index.html