# Can I get application.wadl file using RESTeasy?

Tags: java, web-services, resteasy, wadl

I need to get WADL file for RESTful service. I know that in case using jersey it's available as `http://localhost:8080/application.wadl`. But I use RESTeasy.

Can I do the same in my framework case?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Latest versions:

Quoting [Chapter 49. RESTEasy WADL Support](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.1.4.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html#WADL):

> ## Chapter 49. RESTEasy WADL Support
>
> [49.1. RESTEasy WADL Support for Servlet Container](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.1.4.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html#d4e2321)
>   [49.2. RESTEasy WADL support for Sun JDK HTTP Server](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.1.4.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html#d4e2327)
>   [49.3. RESTEasy WADL support for Netty Container](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.1.4.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html#d4e2337)
>   [49.4. RESTEasy WADL Support for Undertow Container](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.1.4.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html#d4e2342)
>
> RESTEasy has its own support to generate WADL for its resources, and it supports several different containers. The following text will show you how to use this feature in different containers.
>
> #### 49.1. RESTEasy WADL Support for Servlet Container
>
> RESTEasy WADL uses `ResteasyWadlServlet` to support servlet container. It can be registered into `web.xml` to enable WADL feature. Here is an example to show the usages of `ResteasyWadlServlet` in `web.xml`:
>
> ```
> <servlet>
>   <servlet-name>RESTEasy WADL</servlet-name>
>   <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.wadl.ResteasyWadlServlet</servlet-class>
> </servlet>
>
> <servlet-mapping>
>   <servlet-name>RESTEasy WADL</servlet-name>
>   <url-pattern>/application.xml</url-pattern>
> </servlet-mapping>
> ```
>
> The preceding configuration in `web.xml` shows how to enable
>   `ResteasyWadlServlet` and mapped it to `/application.xml`. And then the
>   WADL can be accessed from the configured URL:
>
> ```
> /application.xml
> ```

---

## Workaround for Older versions

There is a workaround: a maven plugin called `maven-wadl-plugin` by the jersey folks that also works to generate WADL for services coded using RESTEasy.

Here's how to use it.

## 1. Add this to your `pom.xml`:

```xml
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-wadl-plugin</artifactId>      
        <version>1.17</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>generate</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>generate</goal>
                </goals>
                <phase>${javadoc-phase}</phase>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <wadlFile>${project.build.outputDirectory}/application.wadl
            </wadlFile>
            <formatWadlFile>true</formatWadlFile>
            <baseUri>http://example.com:8080/rest</baseUri>
            <packagesResourceConfig>
                <param>com.example.rs.resource</param>
            </packagesResourceConfig>
            <wadlGenerators>
                <wadlGeneratorDescription>
                    <className>com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.generators.WadlGeneratorApplicationDoc
                    </className>
                    <properties>
                        <property>
                            <name>applicationDocsFile</name>
                            <value>${basedir}/src/main/doc/application-doc.xml</value>
                        </property>
                    </properties>
                </wadlGeneratorDescription>
                <wadlGeneratorDescription>
                    <className>com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.generators.WadlGeneratorGrammarsSupport
                    </className>
                    <properties>
                        <property>
                            <name>grammarsFile</name>
                            <value>${basedir}/src/main/doc/application-grammars.xml</value>
                        </property>
                    </properties>
                </wadlGeneratorDescription>
            </wadlGenerators>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

Pay attention to the `baseUri` and `packagesResourceConfig` elements. You have to change them to reflect your project's configuration. You may also want to change the plugin's version (I used 1.17).

## 2. Create a /doc folder and add some files.

Create the `src/main/doc/` folder and create the two files below.

File: **application-doc.xml**

Content:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<applicationDocs targetNamespace="http://wadl.dev.java.net/2009/02">
    <doc xml:lang="en" title="A message in the WADL">This is added to the start of the generated application.wadl</doc>
</applicationDocs>
```

File: **application-grammars.xml**

Content:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<grammars xmlns="http://wadl.dev.java.net/2009/02" />
```

## 3. Run the maven command.

Go to the project folder and run the following command:

```
$ mvn compile com.sun.jersey.contribs:maven-wadl-plugin:generate
```

The files `\target\classes\application.wadl` (the WADL itself) and `\target\classes\xsd0.xsd`  (the schema of the resources - it's used by the application.wadl) should be generated.

Edit and use them as you wish.

PS.: Bear in mind that this is a very simple use of the maven-wadl-plugin. It can do a lot more. To know it better, please refer to the zip file in http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/sun/jersey/samples/generate-wadl/1.12/generate-wadl-1.12-project.zip

Answer (score 9):

WADL generation in RESTeasy is a feature not yet implemented.  If you want it go vote for it.

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RESTEASY-166

Answer (score 4):

See [RESTEasy WADL Support](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.1.0.Final/userguide/html/WADL.html) (3.1.0). The snipped below is copied from there

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>RESTEasy WADL</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.wadl.ResteasyWadlServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RESTEasy WADL</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/application.xml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This uses the `ResteasyWadlServlet` and will make the WADL accessible at `/application.xml`.

*Note*:
Rex and Jaskirat have already mentioned previously that [RESTEASY-166](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RESTEASY-166) was used to manage the implementation for this feature. It seems this was completed in 3.0.14.

Answer (score 2):

we can generate a wadl with the help of maven project with POM.XML

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RESTEASY-166 check the comments here..!!