# Generate WADL with RESTEasy (Plugin or Ant)

Tags: java, ant, resteasy, wadl

My team is looking to create WADL files for our web service which uses Ant and RESTEasy.

Is it possible to generate WADL files for RESTEasy through Ant?  Or a plugin?

I am aware of this previously asked question which was answered [using Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14742545/5632178), but this is not helpful in my case.

Comment: We are moving forward with generating a Swagger file to describe the service.

Answer (score 1):

Rest easy now has support for this:

https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy/tree/master/jaxrs/resteasy-wadl

/WEB-INF/web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>RESTEasy WADL</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.wadl.ResteasyWadlServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RESTEasy WADL</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/application.wadl</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: did you ever get this really working? I got a WADL but without grammar section: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44112418/missing-grammar-in-jboss-resteasy-generated-wadl