# How to invoke a Web Service using Java

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, webservice-client

I am new to Web services. I need to invoke a web service whose definition is in http://api.search.live.net/search.wsdl . I need to do a search of any keyword by using this web service. 
I search on the net but could not find any solution. Any idea how to invoke the web service. I need to use Java.

Answer (score 2):

Download [axis2](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/).

After extracting it, under the bin folder there is a tool called wsdl2java, this is used to generate stubs from the WSDL that can communicate with the webservice.

A sample usage would be:

```
WSDL2Java -uri http://api.search.live.net/search.wsdl  -d xmlbeans -s
```

look [here](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/userguide-creatingclients.html) for more details on that tool.

Besides stubs it will also generate all the objects you need.

[Here](http://www.soa.si/2011/09/30/developing-axis2-web-services-with-jax-b-data-binding-in-eclipse/) is a tutorial using axis2 and Eclipse IDE.

Comment: axis2 has a java implementation and you will be working with java code

Comment: axis2 is a **java** framework and it will generate java stubs and objects. it is also one of the most widely used SOAP frameworks in the java world, so getting to know it is a good thing.

Comment: Yes. İ see.. i thought that is a tool. Thank you i will look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://ws.apache.org/ where you will find Axis2 which is probably what you are looking for.

Note that web-services are more generic term than WSDL and have evolved since WSDL was introduced to the point that most services today speak JSON and alike. See more here [RESTEasy or Jersey?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042886/resteasy-or-jersey)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I need to use WSDL it comes from requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I use intelliJ to generate the java code I need from a WSDL.  You can then use this code to do SOAP calls.

Give it the WSDL and it will generate the code, some info can be found here:
http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/generating-wsdl-document-from-java-code.html