# Embedded web server with Rest API's and RESTEasy

Tags: java, web-services, rest, resteasy

I want to create a standalone desktop application with embedded web server. This is my first time writing application like this. I did some research and decided to use JETTY for embedded web server. I found some good tutorials and I have got it running.

Now I'm trying to figure out how to make my services available for the HTML client. I read about REST api's concept. I am trying to find some good tutorials which will help me write REST api's for my application.

All good tutorials I've found so far talk about RESTEasy. Is RESTEasy absolutely required for writing  rest api's? why do we need it? what does it do exactly? I'm confused here. Also, I'd really appreciate if someone can post some good tutorials on web server API's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NOthing is absolutely required for anything.  Especially with REST.  There is absolutely no need to use a particular framework to do a REST service.  As a matter of fact it is not entirely clear what would a framework give you.  What you need is to decide what format you will use to pass data to your service (JSON, XML or plain text key value pairs) and then pick a library for parsing and encoding that format.  That's pretty much it.  The rest of REST (sorry) is just a convention.

Comment: can you post any tutorial of setting up this data exchange convention without using any framework?

Comment: take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042886/resteasy-or-jersey

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you this approach, REST is very flexible and easy to understand. When I did my first web service, I've read REST API Design Rulebook from Mark Masse. Once you know the basics you can use any kind of framework or technology, as MK said.