# Best Restful WebService in Java for API Development for high volume data?

Tags: java, web-services, api, rest

I am developing a webservice using JAVA to provide data using restful API(like facebook's graph API). Which Webservice can I use for developing this? In my Application I am handling large volume of data for processing.

When I give the URL https://mytestsevice.com/search?q=apple

The data should be get from Web Service as,

```
 {"testdata": [
  {
     "id": "9467508",
     "from": {
        "name": "Aguilar",
        "id": "100001732506711"
     },
     "message": "an apple a day keeps the doctor away"
     }
      ]
     }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Which Webservice" ?

Comment: @Tarek There are different Webservices like Apache axis, Jersey etc... From this which one I have to select for my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple choices, all the frameworks are very light and able to handle requests at a good request per second rate. I have used [jersey](https://jersey.java.net/) and [resteasy](http://www.jboss.org/resteasy), both of them have no performance bottlenecks. Probably the reason is that they don't do much except intercepting all the incoming request to their servlet and forward them to the appropriate mapped class. You will gain from the object to JSON or vice-versa mapping functionality as a bonus from these frameworks.

But you need to be careful with the business logic you will be writing, to get the desired performance. As I mentioned, there are no substantial overheads with any of the mentioned frameworks.

Comment: Thank you Juned Ahsan for your useful answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at below questions:

[JAX-RS Frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80799/jax-rs-frameworks)

[Jersey, Apache Wink and RESTEasy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459795/how-to-choose-between-jersey-apache-wink-and-jboss-resteasy)

[RestEasy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572691/is-resteasy-the-right-choice)

and [this](http://wiki.apache.org/ws/StackComparison) comparision.

Hope will help.

Comment: Thank you Tarek for your useful post :)